# Connect to linked MySQL docker client

Tags: docker

I am running MySQL in docker container using the below command.

```
 docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

I can understand how the above command works.
I'm trying to connect the MySQL running in above container from another docker container using the below command.

```
docker run -it --link some-mysql:mysql --rm mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'
```

I don't understand the way above command works quite clearly. I can understand  -it, --link --rm but NOT how the variables MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR,  MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT, MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.

Thanks in advance for your examplanation.

Comment: these are the environment variable which you are trying to open while running the conrtainer to connect t othe other container. https://snipe-it.readme.io/v3.0/docs/docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed on the legacy networking page at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#environment-variables. Those variables are defined inside containers using `--link`. The command is using the environment variables to figure out the port and IP address of the container serving MySQL.

However, these days you can just create a network and connect to the container by name.